# how to create Wave shape with css

Tags: css, svg

I'm trying to recreate this image with `svg`:

[image]

Here is fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/g7kgdo8u/

But I need this image with css.
 Is it possible?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Albzi I can not create a waveform and create a straight line...

Comment: You might want to take a look at [this](https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/)

Comment: @Paulie_D all Well, I'm trying..

Comment: @OluwasayoBabalola thanks you

Comment: Using css means applying some style to an element. And using empty elements only for styling purpose is not recommended. why do you need to do that in css?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `border-bottom-left-radius` and `border-bottom-right-radius`

```css
div {  
  background-color: lightgrey;
  height: 55px;
  width: 300px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
}

div:after {
  content:"";
  display: block;
  background-color: cornflowerblue;
  height: 50px;
  width: 300px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 50%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also do it with a `radial-gradient`:

```css
.box {
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  background:
  radial-gradient(circle at 50% -300%,blue 90%,transparent 90.5%),
  radial-gradient(circle at 60% -300%,grey 90%,transparent 90.5%);
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: This is good, but I want to use a header at the top of a box, which is damaged in large size. It also seems to have a blur effect.https://jsfiddle.net/o6fk1mun/

Comment: @Rasoul this the side effect of using CSS and not SVG :)